# Are named miraak cultists normal?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I was wondering if it is normal to run into a named cultist because I have run into a couple and was wondering if it is normal.

Are they supposed to be like the generals/high priests of the cult?

Comment: No, it isn't normal. Like I was saying in chat, I think your saved game is messed up.

Comment: How would you fix this problem

Comment: I don't know of a good way to fix it. I would either go back to a really old save before it started happening, or I'd start a new game. :-/

Comment: Ok i will try and start a new game and see if that works

Comment: I imagine it will fix it, but the problem is you'll lose all your progress. It seems like you ran across a really bad bug.

Comment: I will post when I get back to where I was at in the old game

Comment: Good luck. I hope that was just a fluke in your old saved game.

Answer (score 2):

I've had a few run ins with them. I've not seen anything new from "named cultists" to "cultists".

They will continue to attack you. Until The quest, Dragonborn is completed.

Once your partaking in the quest there will be level based cultists:

- Cultist Adept

The Cultist Adept is a medium to high level regular cultist. They are not as powerful as an Ascendant Cultist.

- Ascendant Cultist

An Ascendant Cultist is the strongest form of regular Cultist. They are not as powerful as the boss level Arch Cultist, but are more powerful than the Cultist Adepts. They use lightning spells, including Lightning Storm.

- Master Cultist

The Master Cultist is the second strongest cultist, and the weakest boss cultists. They attack much like a regular cultist using fire or shock spells. Master cultists use the same spell set as ascendant cultists. They have more health and magicka than other cultists.

- Arch Cultist

An Arch Cultist is the strongest form of Cultist. They are typically bosses and use lightning spells, including Lightning Storm. At times they can be very sloppy and slow and can be taken advantage of at this time.